# Dixon test (Q-test) - different tables found online

Tags: outliers

I have data from temperature measurements. Unfortunately, sensors tend to have problems and to register unnormally high temperatures. Some cases are easy to detect, others are not, and I have too much data to do it by hand. To sort out the data, I would like to use a Dixon test (Q-test).

For each timepoint of each experimental treatment, I have n=3 sensors (hence n=3 values). To check whether the highest value is an outlier, I:

- reorder the values.
- calculate using R: Q= (vector[3] - vector[2])/(vector[2]-vector[1])
- compare Q to Qcrit (if Q < Qcrit, highest value is not an outlier)

I looked at the Qcrit values online (i.e. Dixon table) but found different tables. For e.g. n=3 and first risk thresholds at 10%, 5% and 1%:

- tables giving Qcrit(10%)=0.886, Qcrit(5%)=0.941 and Qcrit(1%)=0.988. See [here](http://www.watpon.com/table/dixontest.pdf).
- tables giving Qcrit(10%)=0.941, Qcrit(5%)=0.970 and Qcrit(1%)=0.994. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_Q_test).

*Note I have more links to the different tables but can't provide them (not enough Reputation Points).*

So I'm not sure why these differences. I suppose there's a trick somewhere. Could you please tell me:

- why do these difference exist?
- what I'd better use?

Comment: It is likely that some charts are for two-sided tests (any outlier), and others are for specifically either high or low outliers.

Comment: You're right, I've found the right tables [here] (http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/eqc.2008.23.issue-1/eqc.2008.5/eqc.2008.5.xml) when adding "one-sided" keyword . Thanks; I'll modify the wiki page. Also, how to mark the question solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dixon test can be used to test for outliers that are high, low, or both. In the latter situation (both), a two-sided test must be used.  When presenting tables, many sites do not distinguish for which situation (1-sided or 2-sided) the values apply.  To figure out which values are valid for your test, find two tables with differing of values. The table with the smaller critical values for a given level $\alpha$ will be for 1-sided tests, and the other table for 2-sided tests.